# how to retrieve the short commit id for a subdirectory (on windows slave node) in jenkins pipeline

Tags: git, batch-file, jenkins-pipeline

In my git repository there is a sub folder abc. I need the short commit id for the sub folder. this repository is on a windows slave node. I m trying to retrieve the short commit id from jenkins file.

I am able to retrieve the short commit id of the git repository using the following command:

```
def SHORT_COMMIT_ID_APP = bat 
    (returnStdout: true, script: "@git log -n 1 --pretty=format:\'%%h\'").trim()
```

but if I add `-- abc`  (abc is the subfolder in the git repository)to the same command, it is returning a blank value.

```
def SHORT_COMMIT_ID_APP = bat 
    (returnStdout: true, script: "@git log -n 1 --pretty=format:\'%%h\' -- abc").trim()
```

and when I run the following command on the slave node directly

```
git log -n 1 --pretty=format:'%h' -- abc
```

it returns the correct value short commit id

how can I get the short commit id of the subfolder on jenkins?

Comment: add a space before the --

Comment: What does `%%h` stand for?

Comment: @aschipfl: OP is using a command-interpreter that "eats" one layer of `%` signs for whatever purpose, the same way `make` eats one dollar sign so that if you want to pass `$` to a command you have to spell it `$$`. In this case, to pass `%h` to `git log`, he must spell it `%%h`.

Comment: Thanks, @torek, so it is not a meta-variable `%%h` of a [`for` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) in the Windows Command Prompt; then I do not see any connection to the tag [tag:batch-file]...

Comment: @aschipfl: I am new to batch scripting and wanted to write abatch script for running the git command. there is slight typo ,in above query the following command on slave node is working fine : git log -n 1 --pretty=format:'%h' -- abc

but not able to get it to run from jenkins

Comment: @CodeWizard:Yes I have added space before --.Still not working

Comment: Please [edit] the question and correct the _space_ typo since it appears not to be the integral issue. In a batch script do not escape apostrophes `'` (like `\'`) as they have no special meaning and the `\ `is not the escape character (it's `^`)...